# Smart UV Image getting pixelated

Tags: texturing, uv, image, uv-image-editor

I apply a image texture to this Smart UV unwrap and the image comes out pixelated in some areas of the UV. The image is completely fine and has no visible pixels to it. What can I do to get rid of these unusual pixels [image]

Comment: Can you show us an image of your UV layout?
Most likely, some faces are very small there

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/92d39c9a293722f93f980c262161f0d1.png yes it is very small

here's an even closer look https://i.gyazo.com/5b14426913ea9880a7a75e3cf81a6811.png

Comment: Looking at your UV i may guess that it is due to flipped normals... Try to press Alt+N and choose Recalculate Outside... did it help?

Comment: @MikoCG I tried and nothing happened, I don't have any modifiers either, the model isn't jagged at all either, so I have no idea what this might be... I cant find anything that helps either

Comment: P.S this only happens when I smart UV unwrap, Normal UV unwrapping does not end up having these random jagged texture. I am using Smart UV because the objects has too many polygons and it takes about 20 mins to fully unwrap normally

Comment: is it possible to share your file so that I can look what may be the cause?